# Grid Search in RidgeCV Regression

Tags: machine-learning, python, ridge-regression

I am trying to apply `grid-search` on `RidgeCV Regression`. Following python code that I had tried but I am getting error `TypeError: len() of unsized object`. I have no so knowledge on Regression. I do not know whether is it poosible to apply on `regression`?.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import RidgeCV
RD_model = RidgeCV()

tuned_parameters = {'alphas': list(x / 10 for x in range(0, 101)),
                    'fit_intercept': [True,False], 
                    'normalize' :[False, True],
                    'gcv_mode': ['eigen', 'auto', 'svd'],
                    'store_cv_values': [False, True]}

from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
RD = GridSearchCV(RD_model, tuned_parameters, cv = 10)

RD.fit(X_train, y_train) # error here
```

## Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-168-560e8122d624> in <module>()
----> 1 RD.fit(X_train, y_train)

/home/rezwan/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py in fit(self, X, y, groups, **fit_params)
    636                                   error_score=self.error_score)
    637           for parameters, (train, test) in product(candidate_params,
--> 638                                                    cv.split(X, y, groups)))
    639 
    640         # if one choose to see train score, "out" will contain train score info

/home/rezwan/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py in __call__(self, iterable)
    777             # was dispatched. In particular this covers the edge
    778             # case of Parallel used with an exhausted iterator.
--> 779             while self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
    780                 self._iterating = True
    781             else:

/home/rezwan/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py in dispatch_one_batch(self, iterator)
    623                 return False
    624             else:
--> 625                 self._dispatch(tasks)
    626                 return True
    627 

/home/rezwan/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py in _dispatch(self, batch)
    586         dispatch_timestamp = time.time()
    587         cb = BatchCompletionCallBack(dispatch_timestamp, len(batch), self)
--> 588         job = self._backend.apply_async(batch, callback=cb)
    589         self._jobs.append(job)
    590 

/home/rezwan/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/_parallel_backends.py in apply_async(self, func, callback)
    109     def apply_async(self, func, callback=None):
    110         """Schedule a func to be run"""
--> 111         result = ImmediateResult(func)
    112         if callback:
    113             callback(result)

/home/rezwan/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/_parallel_backends.py in __init__(self, batch)
    330         # Don't delay the application, to avoid keeping the input
    331         # arguments in memory
--> 332         self.results = batch()
    333 
    334     def get(self):

/home/rezwan/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py in __call__(self)
    129 
    130     def __call__(self):
--> 131         return [func(*args, **kwargs) for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
    132 
    133     def __len__(self):

/home/rezwan/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    129 
    130     def __call__(self):
--> 131         return [func(*args, **kwargs) for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
    132 
    133     def __len__(self):

/home/rezwan/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py in _fit_and_score(estimator, X, y, scorer, train, test, verbose, parameters, fit_params, return_train_score, return_parameters, return_n_test_samples, return_times, error_score)
    435             estimator.fit(X_train, **fit_params)
    436         else:
--> 437             estimator.fit(X_train, y_train, **fit_params)
    438 
    439     except Exception as e:

/home/rezwan/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/ridge.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
   1112                                   gcv_mode=self.gcv_mode,
   1113                                   store_cv_values=self.store_cv_values)
-> 1114             estimator.fit(X, y, sample_weight=sample_weight)
   1115             self.alpha_ = estimator.alpha_
   1116             if self.store_cv_values:

/home/rezwan/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/ridge.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
   1029         v, Q, QT_y = _pre_compute(X, y, centered_kernel)
   1030         n_y = 1 if len(y.shape) == 1 else y.shape[1]
-> 1031         cv_values = np.zeros((n_samples * n_y, len(self.alphas)))
   1032         C = []
   1033 

TypeError: len() of unsized object
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `GridSearchCV` is operaing over a [`RidgeCV`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.RidgeCV.html) object, that's expecting to take a *list* of `alphas`, and a scalar of each of the other parameters. However, `GridSearchCV` does not know that, and is passing it a single parameter at a time from each list, including `alphas`. When your `RidgeCV` object gets a scalar for `alphas`, it tries to take its `len`, and fails.

There are several ways of correcting this. The easiest (and least efficient) is using [`Ridge`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Ridge.html) instead, and using a list `alpha: list(x / 10 for x in range(0, 101)),`.